# Did Apple remove the &= operator from Swift 1.2 for booleans?

Tags: swift

XCode 6.3 returns an compile error on a `&=` with booleans.

`'&=' is unavailable: use the '&&' operator instead`

example :

```
var myBool = false
myBool &= true
```

Any idea why it was removed ?

Comment: Probably because they couldn't figure out how to make it work consistently.

Comment: In **WHAT** context?

Comment: A concrete example would be helpful, `var a = 123 ; let b = 454 ; a &= b` compiles without problems. (However, it does not work with booleans. But I don't know if it ever worked with booleans.)

Comment: Yep it worked with the previous version of Swift

Answer (score 2):

I would guess they removed it because `&=` is a bitwise operator for other types so for it to be a logic operator on booleans would be inconsistent (and bitwise operation on `Bool` is probably frowned-upon), so really it ought to be `&&=`.  Which isn’t defined possibly because it’s of minimal utility.  But if you want it:

```
infix operator &&= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

func &&=(inout lhs: Bool, @autoclosure rhs: ()->Bool) {
    lhs = lhs && rhs
}

var myBool = true
myBool &&= false
```

Comment: `&&=` operator seems to already exist in Swift. See point *Assignment* in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html

Comment: Docs may be out of date, I think that operator was removed from the std lib in Xcode 6 beta 4.

Comment: Yup, checked and it was only ever defined as an operator in very in early versions, and never actually implemented in any function, then removed altogether later. Docs are wrong.