# Implementing ||= and &&= operators: operator implementation without matching operator declaration

Tags: swift

I would like to have "assigning or" and "assigning and" operators. According to [Swift Standard Library Operators Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html), these operators are defined in standard library.

I tried to implement these operators for `Bool` values:

```
func ||= (inout lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) {
  lhs = lhs || rhs
}

func &&= (inout lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) {
  lhs = lhs && rhs
}
```

But the compiler complains: `operator implementation without matching operator declaration`

This can be fixed by defining operators:

```
infix operator ||= { associativity right precedence 90 }

infix operator &&= { associativity right precedence 90 }
```

But I am not sure this is the right thing to do. Why do definitions from the standard library not work? Also, I noticed that according to operator reference standard library has no implementations of these operators for any type. Why is that? Is this an oversight or something intentional?

Comment: Interesting. But your implementation looks all right for me.

Comment: @J.Wang yeah, it seems to work fine, but I was wondering if reimplementing these operators is the right thing to do

Comment: @dfri ah, I see, thanks! Will you post this as an answer?

Comment: Uh, this kind of operators are not good for your code quality. Just the fact that you need them means that you are preferring using mutable variables over constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs regarding operators are outdated, which has been noted previously in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593673/did-apple-remove-the-operator-from-swift-1-2-for-booleans/29593965#29593965); I quote user Airspeed Velocity:

> Yup, checked and it (*ed. note: referring to operator `&&=`*) was only
>   ever defined as an operator in very in early versions, and never
>   actually implemented in any function, then removed altogether later.
>   Docs are wrong.

You can easily see which operators that are actually defined natively, by `Cmd`-clicking `Swift` in

```
import Swift
```

in e.g. a playground.

Alternatively, have a look at standard operators section in the the source code of `Policy.swift`:

- [`swift/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift)

In both the above, it's apparent that neither `&&=` nor `||=` are defined natively.

---

If you're interested in how these operators were implemented (back in Swift 1.1), the following post could be of interest:

- [Implementing Ruby’s ||= operator in Swift using @autoclosure](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/10/implementing-rubys-operator-in-swift/)